# Erro de Schema Gtk/Glade

Tags: c, gtk

Boa noite pessoal, tudo bom ?

Estou com um erro na hora de executar uma interface criada para um programa C utilizando o GTK/GLADE.

O programa compila normalmente mas na hora da execução ele alega que está faltando a libgtk-3-0.dll
e a única parte que tem erro é quando dou o comando pra instalar todos pacotes de uma vez.

Segue imagem do único local que está dando erro no console msys64

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tenta baixar as bibliotecas separadas, ou tenta fazer a interface sem o glade para ver se funciona normalmente

Comment: Cara, consegui montar a interface sem o Glade.
E estudando mais, conseguir montar com o Glade também.
Muito obrigado!

Desculpa a demora em responder.

Comment: Tranquilo, eu nunca me dei muito bem com o glade, usei algumas vezes só para ver quais componentes estavam disponíveis para usar e algumas propriedades, já para fazer uma aplicação, já chega ser um pouco mais chato, principalmente o glade 3, que não tem opção para gerar o source, deve ser gerado por *ui*.